# iOS advertising beacon in background

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I devlope advertising data app in iOS.
My app advertising data is good in foreground.
But I want to advertising beacon data in ios background.
I set up  background-peripheral setting.
and advertisingData

```
advertisingData = [CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: localName, 
CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [serviceUUID]]`
```

that's well show foreground
when, my app stopped(home button), ios beacon scanned,
but all data not showing.
I already know in background mode, services gone `overflow' area,
but is there anything you can do without a offical way?

Comment: Advertisement beacon in background is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote my master thesis about this topic. The answer is no, it is not possible to make an iOS App advertise beacon data in background.

It doesn't work with the traditional CoreLocation APIs. What you may be able to do, is to replicate the iBeacon behavior in your app while supporting background broadcast and detection, but I did not manage to make the broadcasted signal to be recognised as a beacon.

Check this answer for additional information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19941436/3726570

Comment: i have check your link,

but link content is scanning,

is this same?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. The service UUIDs are moved to an overflow area (that's the only type of information you can broadcast with this method). It's how other iOS device can still receive UUIDs if an iOS is broadcasting in the background. The overflow area is encrypted. It can be reverse engineered.