# "AirLocate" sample code calibrate's option does not work

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-location, ibeacon, calibration

I'm an iBeacon feature newbie and I'm running the `AirLocate` sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AirLocate/Introduction/Intro.html) to configure an iOS device as an iBeacon device for learning and testing. As the "readme" file in the project says, I've launched the app on an iPhone 5 and an iPad 4, both running iOS 8. I've set one of them as target device by switching on the "Enable" switch in the "Configuration" option of the app, and I've chosen the "Calibration" option in the app in the other device. The target device is supposed to be displayed in the table of the calibration device, but I'm isplayed nothing.

I've swept the roles of both devices (target-calibration), but none of them seems to detect the other one.

What could I be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know whether AirLocate was updated but with iOS 8 you have to ask the user the permission to access the Bluetooth. If you don't, there's no hope it's going to work, and since AirLocate was first developed for iOS7 actually I don't remember whether it embedded this feature.

Comment: @PlayItGreen Thanks, what exactly should I do to make this run on iOS 8? Or do you know another (free) app to calibrate and configure iOS 7 & 8 iBeacons?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible answer. I had developed my own app to configure iBeacons, but when I updated to iOS 8 I had to add this line of code to get it working

```
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

Now you can try add this line to `AirLocate` (if it does not have) and answer `yes` when asking to access your resources. Place this in a `ViewController` you access, otherwise won't get fired.

Another way could be to build your own app to handle `iBeacons` following tutorials or Apple's Doc, actually it's not such an effort.

There are for sure anyway other free apps, but I don't know, try to google.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. Updating the Info.plist file is also needed.

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to mention the info.plist file!

Answer (score 1):

Now it is working for iOS 8 after applying the changes described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079530/apple-airlocation-demo-app-ranging-not-shows-beacons)