# Copy beacon signal

Tags: bluetooth, beacon

Is there any way to copy the signal of a Beacon without having physical access to it?I just want to know if it's possible, don't start telling me that's illegal, I know

I have tried nothing yet I'm still searching in forums , but I cannot find enough information about that topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cloning a standard Bluetooth beacon (iBeacon, AltBeacon, Eddystone-UID) is super simple.  See my [related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20227511/1461050) where I described cloning one a the Apple Store to trigger a welcome message in their app.

Since the above beacon types are advertised in clear text (no encryption), you can think of them like a road sign or billboard.  Just as you can't stop others from photographing a sign, you really can't stop folks from reading a beacon identifier and making a copy of it.

What's more, the iBeacon identifier, for example, is only 20 bytes.  Copying it is about as trivial as it gets.

There are other beacon formats like Eddystone-EID and Gimbal that have a cryptographic hash in the advertised identifier that cannot be easily cloned.