# Advantages of only advertising data vs connecting BLE devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Let Say I have a peripheral that is advertising data that is encoded into its UUID .  The central scanning sees this UUID and and knows to turn the hexadecimal UUID to decimal and from there take out certain numbers by groups such as the first 4, then the next 6, then the next 4.  It has certain functions to put these numbers into.  Is there any advantages of this instead of connecting to the central device and then just trading information.  Would it be faster? What about when you take into account multiple centrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advantages:

- Practically a broadcasting solution, as such, any number of clients can be served at the same time
- Similar scheme is used for [beacons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906988/what-is-the-ibeacon-bluetooth-profile)

Disadvantages:

- In iOS, advertisement data is not designed to be updated frequently. Frequent changes may lead to stack corruption.
- Very low data rates can be achieved this way.

It seems to be a general issue that broadcasting is not supported with BLE implementations. If you have to communicate to a great number of peers, then IP based solutions may better suit your needs. (Detect with BLE and communicate on IP.) There are countless options to choose from, and which one is best highly depends on your actual application.

Comment: In iOS, could I couple these two methods? By this I mean I connect to devices and when I hit 6 connections and theres more devices requesting connections I just switch to the encoded advertisement method.  Do you think this would be possible in iOS?

Comment: If you are planning to connect several clients, then I suggest you think in an IP based solution and use BLE to find the peers only. The encoded advertisement does not seem to be a truly viable option for multicast communication. But if you are planning to do something like a beacon and change the advertisement data infrequently, then it is a possible alternative.