# How to scan iBeacon in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ibeacon

I have a project that scans a iBeacon, and i had also learned this [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ibeacon/)

I have also googled so many projects for that but can't get expected result.

Here i had some code that I write for scan a beacon

```
    listenToBeaconEvents() {
        this.events.subscribe("didRangeBeaconsInRegion", data => {
        // update the UI with the beacon list
        this.zone.run(() => {
            let json = data.region;
            console.log("-------Beacons-------" + JSON.stringify(json));
            this.beacons.push({
            uuid: JSON.stringify(json.uuid),
            identifier: JSON.stringify(json.identifier),
            typename: JSON.stringify(json.typeName)
            });
        });
    }
```

But my question is if i don't have an UUID of particular beacon then how i can search the beacon?

Please Help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you cannot find beacons without a particular UUID -- the platform simply does not allow you to do this.  Android has no such restriction.

See this related question for a more detailed explanation:

[iOS iBeacon: How to get all of proximityUUID programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163290/ios-ibeacon-how-to-get-all-of-proximityuuid-programmatically)

Comment: thanks for reply
but my question was how (pragmatically) i found a nearby Beacons?