# Receive BLE beacon with Raspberry Pi

Tags: rest, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am looking for a tutorial on how to receive an iBeacon signal with a Raspberry PI.
What I am trying to do is monitor a zone of our warehouse. Once a beacon that advertises specific information enters that zone the rasperry Pi should send a REST request to a webservice.

I've found this: [Can RaspberryPi with BLE Dongle detect iBeacons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733228/can-raspberrypi-with-ble-dongle-detect-ibeacons)   but it does not quite answer my question. Does anyone know of a good tutorial how to implement something like the above?

(the easier the better, I am not exactly a programming whiz ... :-) )

Cheers,
Vitus

Answer (score 0):

My company is working on tools to make doing this easier, but we do not have a tutorial available yet.  We are the ones who posted the information you referenced: [Can RaspberryPi with BLE Dongle detect iBeacons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733228/can-raspberrypi-with-ble-dongle-detect-ibeacons)

If you want to call a ReST service when an iBeacon is detected, you can use it with the detection script we provided.  As the detection script runs, it writes out the identifiers of any iBeacons it sees.  What you would need to do is write a separate program that reads in the output of this script, looks for identifiers that it cares about, then calls the ReST service when it sees them.

Connecting two programs by taking the standard output of one and reading it with another is a very common programming technique on Linux.  You would run our program with `ibeacon_scan -b` and it would output the information below:

```
2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 6 -59
E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0 6 9 -55
74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935 0 73 -50
```

You would then read this information in with your second program line by line, parsing out the three part identifier from each line.  And then call your ReST Service if the identifiers match the iBeacon you are looking for.

The specifics of how you do this depend on what programming language you want to use.  You could do it in C, Ruby, Perl, Java or any other language supported by the Raspberry Pi.  If you have a client library for your ReST service, you probably want to build this program in whatever language that client library uses.

Full disclosure:  I am Chief Engineer for Radius Networks.