# Raspberry pi doesn't show rssi values when ./ibeacon_scan run

Tags: ibeacon, rssi

I am using my raspberry pi as ibeacon scanner ,and with the pipes i output the values in .php file and than i send it to my backend.But the problem is that this script shows onlyUUID,minor,major and power,but i would like to see RSSI outputs.Anyone knows some good reference?

Comment: Presumably if that information is collected by the adapter and made available through the bluetooth stack, you can modify the script to output it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSSI is included in the raw output of `hcidump` so you can capture its value and output it along with the other values.  Though this wasn't included originally in our iBeacon scan script, we recently received a suggestion to add it so I've updated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733228/can-raspberrypi-with-ble-dongle-detect-ibeacons/21790504#21790504) with an outline of how to include RSSI in the output of the script.