# How can i get rssi strength in c?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, scanning, rssi, intel-edison

I want to get rssi strength value with bluez code. ( in c language)

I already have code that check rssi but, it doesn't work well.

It can't find what i want to find ( my phone, my raspberry pi ).

Code that i use is intel-edison-playground in github.

Comment: you have to provide more information to get accurate help

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417017/bluetooth-le-signal-strength-linux/24417605#24417605