# need an alternative to bluez APIs having following features

Tags: c++, ubuntu, bluetooth, bluez

I am developing a bluetooth module. I need the features-

```
1>device discovery,  
2>device connection,  
3> inter-device communication,  
4>RSSI to know the approximate distance between them(it need not be accurate).
```

I developed the feature earlier using "bluez" stack APIs. But there I do not find feature- RSSI to know the approximate distance between them(it need not be accurate).
So, I want 2 options-

```
1> to use an alternative to "bluez" or  
2> to request "bluez" to include RSSI module.
```

I am developing in "ubuntu" Linux environment using C++ and "GTK".

Please suggest me what should I do?
I just need the distance between 2 devices by any means using c++, if any linux command is there, maybe I can use the system() or its alternatives.. I wish to check if the distance between devices is less than 10 fts. or greater than 10 fts. That's the only thing I need.

Answer (score 1):

BlueZ does allow you to get the RSSI between two devices. See my answer here:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24417605/2215147

However, as you probably already read, the accuracy is not great and in general it is not recommended that the distance is approximated through RSSI. Please see links below for reference:-

- [Things You Should Know About Bluetooth Range](https://blog.nordicsemi.com/getconnected/things-you-should-know-about-bluetooth-range)
- [Using BLE for Indoor Positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214988/using-ble-for-indoor-positioning/57266822#57266822)