# How to receive raw bluetooth package on NAO robot

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, hci, nao-robot

I want to receive ibeacon information on nao robot using Bluetooth adapter, and let naoqi use it.
I want to implement Linux Bluetooth tools such as hcidump to read raw Bluetooth package and extract ibeaon information.

However, I can't find a Practical solution to make it.

Can any one offer me a practical solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm maybe too late but, I tried to do exactly the same and it's impossible due to old nao linux kernel version 2.6
Bluez software support for Bluetooth low energy comes with version 5.0 and it need a linux kernel version >= 3.5

Answer (score 0):

The Nau is Linux based, so it should support scanning for beacons using BlueZ, although you may need to install the package. Of course, the Nau will need a Bluetooth LE sensor, but you should be able to plug one in to its USB port.

Check out this guide for the Raspberry Pi.  It should be applicable:

[Can RaspberryPi with BLE Dongle detect iBeacons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733228/can-raspberrypi-with-ble-dongle-detect-ibeacons)

Comment: Thank you for you answer,but I can't find any package manage tools on nao robot's OS, and i can't find 'make' command.Even if I can install hcidump tool, how can i using the command in naoqi software which make nao robot working?

Comment: yes for the moment no make, gcc nor any build tools are installed on the robot. But you could for instance download a NAO virtual machine image on the aldebaran website, who will include all that tools, then you build the binary on the virtual machine, then you upload it on the robot. And that's all !