# BLE scan on Raspberry Pi does not work in Java via ProcessBuilder / Runtime

Tags: java, unix, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to scan the BLE devices on the Raspberry Pi in Java.
I used the [posted BLE scanning script (ibeacon_scan.sh)](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/beacon-dev-kit-update.html)  from the [answer of jjnebeker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733228/can-raspberrypi-with-ble-dongle-detect-ibeacons). It works really great, when I start it on my UNIX laptop with the following Java code:

```
public void init(String[] commands){
  // commands -> {"/bin/bash","-c","/<PATH>/ibeacon_scan.sh"}
  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
  processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
  Process process = processBuilder.start();
  createAndStartProcessOutputHandlerThread(process);
}

private Thread createAndStartProcessOutputHandlerThread(Process process) {
  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Scanner scan = null;
      try {
        scan = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
        while (true) {
            if(scan.hasNext()){
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                LOG.info("LINE: ", line);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if(scan != null) {
            scan.close();
        }
    }
  });
   thread.start();
   return thread;
}
```

I started the script as sudo on the Raspberry Pi and I get only empty lines
but no other informations as exceptions or something else :(

EDIT:
The script runs correctly when I execute it in the shell on the Raspberry Pi.

I have no idea how to fix this problem.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: Are you running the script as `root` or using `sudo` when you try it from the shell?

Comment: I tried both ways and they worked