# How can i reprogram a iBeacon in ios?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I need to reprogram a iBeacon using ios, I want to reset the UUID and password of the beacon.
If anybody is having any information regarding that please help.

Thanks

Comment: To initialize a beacon region identified by an proximityUUID, major and minor values use function - (id)initWithProximityUUID:(NSUUID *)proximityUUID major:(CLBeaconMajorValue)major minor:(CLBeaconMinorValue)minor identifier:(NSString *)identifier; in CLBeaconRegion. I dont think a hardware beacon will allow reset, if it then vendors would provide a third party API with funcitons .

Answer (score 4):

This is implementation-specific and depends on your beacon hardware. Some beacons allow you to make a Bluetooth connection and update these properties. Others have it hardcoded. There are other possibilities. Contact your hardware vendor.

Comment: The ones that my company bought came with a MacOS X app that allowed changing settings. I wasn't aware that iBeacons had a password - they have just a UUID and a major/minor code.

Comment: @gnasher Any Bluetooth LE device that uses the right format for its [advertisement](http://www.warski.org/blog/2014/01/how-ibeacons-work/) can be an iBeacon, from a tiny coin-cell powered dedicated device to a desktop computer. The *advertisement* data contains UUID, major, and minor values, but the device itself can certainly allow connections, including passwords, and all kinds of additional interactions. *Contact your hardware vendor* is absolutely the right advice.

Comment: @gnasher729 actually, iBeacons support UUID, major/minor int, and a string identifier value.

Comment: @JAL CoreLocation or other APIs may allow you to associate a string identifier with a beacon, but that is not part of the advertisement data. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19040616/293819) for a breakdown of the BLE advertisement packet.