# iBeacons: how to get broadcasted beacon power (txPower)

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

iBeacons seem to broadcast their txPower parameter (report RSSI power at 1 meter distance) which is used in calculating `beacon.accuracy` and `beacon.proximity` properties (details on iBeacon advertisements packet can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906988/what-is-the-ibeacon-bluetooth-profile)).

However, `CLBeacon` class does not seem to have a property for txPower. Is there a way I can get txPower using Core Location framework, or need I to go down to Core Bluetooth? The reason I need this, is I want to experiment with custom beacon accuracy/proximity calculation for very quick beacon immediate range discovery. In this circumstances reverse calculating txPower from `accuracy` is no helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not get this value programmatically with either `CoreLocation` or `CoreBluetooth`.  Apple blocks access to all iBeacon data with `CoreBluetooth` (See my breakdown of this [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html).)  Similarly with `CoreLocation` it is simply not exposed in the `CLBeacon` class as you have seen.

Since you say you can't to do a reverse-calculation, then the only other ways I can think of to do this are:

1. Use an Android, OSX Mavericks, or Linux device, which offer no such restrictions on reading this field.
2. Make a lookup table in your iOS app of all your iBeacons (with unique UUID/major/minor values vs. their txPower value)

Option 2 above obviously requires that you assign unique identifiers to all your iBeacons under test.

Comment: Locate app is showing txPower value in iOS.
How they did this can you please guide me.

Comment: As the author of the Locate app for iOS, I can confirm it doesn't read the txPower from a beacon transmission.  The calibrate screen lets you calculate the txPower you should configure.   But it can't tell you what it already is in beacon transmissions.