# Reading iBeacon measuredPower in iOS

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

According to the ibeacon protocol "measuredPower" is supposed to be sent by every ibeacon in its advertising packet as the last value after uuid, major & minor values. However, the iOS corelocation service does not have any method which returns this "measuredPower". Also, if we reconfigure an ibeacon and change its txPower then the beacon should ideally advertise a different "measuredPower". Do all beacons do this? And how do we fetch the measuredPower of a beacon in iOS/corelocation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iBeacons: how to get broadcasted beacon power (txPower)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001702/ibeacons-how-to-get-broadcasted-beacon-power-txpower)

Comment: thanks Cameron, that link was pretty informative and so was the answer and article by david young http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly, it's not possible on iOS. The closest you have is the `RSSI` on `CLBeacon`. Given a known distance, you should be able to calculate the signal power.