# Weak Bluetooth Signal iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there a way to generate a very low-energy Bluetooth signal from the iPhone so that another device could only detect the signal if it was very close to the emitting device? Perhaps using the iBeacon technology? [What is the iBeacon Bluetooth Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906988/what-is-the-ibeacon-bluetooth-profile?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `CoreLocation` iBeacons. [See this tutorial on how to setup your device as a broadcasting iBeacon.](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-programming-ibeacons-tutorial/) In the devices searching for it you can monitor the `RSSI` value to determine how close you are.

As you can see in the tutorial that `CoreLocation` gives you `CLBeacon` objects of broadcasting devices in the vicity. You can then access their `proximity` property if you want Apple defined distances:

```
typedef {
   CLProximityUnknown,
   CLProximityImmediate,
   CLProximityNear,
   CLProximityFar
} CLProximity;
```

Comment: wow this is a much more informative answer then I was expecting. is there a way to get the exact distance/do you know how close CLProximityImmediate is in meters?

Comment: It's based off `RSSI` which is simply signal strength. It can be affected by walls, people, glass, etc. To answer your question there is no way to get the exact distance.

Comment: Also, you can't transmit iBeacon packets unless your transmitting app is in the foreground.  The receiving app can be triggered from the background though.