# Is this the correct layout to detect iBeacons with AltBeacon's Android Beacon Library?

Tags: ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I have successfully modified the [reference implementation app](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) of the [Android Beacon Library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library) using the following [beacon layout](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconParser.java#L61), so that it detects an iBeacon device that I have at hand:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
               setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }
}
```

Being new to the internals of BLE packets, I'm not sure if this is the correct layout to use. The library endorses the [AltBeacon](http://altbeacon.org/) standard and its documentation does not mention how to detect iBeacon devices.

- Will this code detect *all* iBeacon devices? i.e. is the `m:` prefix too restrictive or is it the right byte sequence that matches the iBeacon spec?
- Similarly, does the rest of the layout exactly match the iBeacon spec?

Reference:

- [Example of an iBeacon packet seen on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19040616/20226)

Comment: The reference application is down now..

Comment: @BlueTrin Thanks, updated the link to the new repo.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This worked for me: "m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"

I don't think you need to match the 4c00 part because that is the manufacturer id, so you can probably leave that off and start with m:2-3=0215  Everything else looks right, and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks! From testing with Estimote beacons I can confirm that the `m:2-3=0215` change is indeed necessary.

Comment: This worked for me also..i used..

 beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

Comment: This detects Estimote beacons very efficiently..but i have another Roximity Beacon..its not getting detected..what is the beaconLayout for roximity beacons

Comment: How do you read that layout? What is m, i and p? I have an out-of-the-box beacon bought from China. By using Bluetooth LE Scanner app, I was able to find the beacon's UUID, major and minor. But how do I find the UUID pattern to put it into `setBeaconLayout`?

Comment: @AimanB Kindly refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319682/correct-layout-to-detect-kontakt-beacon-on-android-with-altbeacon. In this, m: Manufacturer Data, i: Proximity UUID, i: Major Number, i : Minor Number, p: Signal Power,d : battery level. They represent byte offset. (You need to add 6 while counting).Eg: Manufacturer ID is in between 8th and 9th  in the string "m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24".

Comment: is there a way to scan for any beacon around regardless if its estimote or not ?

Comment: The iBeacon spec does require the manufacturer ID to be 0x4c00, so yes you do need that part. I have also tested beacons with manufacturer IDs set to other values and they are not detected by various apps.

Comment: There have been two proposed patterns and some confusion over which is correct:

"m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"

and

"m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24

Can someone speak to which of these will detect iBeacons from all manufacturers?

Comment: @Landon I suspect either should work. One is just more verbose than the other.

Answer (score 5):

You can download the [iBeacon spec](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/) (click "Download Artwork and Specifications").

In the current version the Company ID *must* be `0x4C00`, and the beacon type must be `0x0215`. All other fields are required, and as you specified.

So yes, you are exactly correct and it will detect all compliant iBeacons.

OT: It also specifies that the advertising interval must be 100ms, but I seriously doubt all iBeacons stick to that.