# raspberry pi beacon parser for android beacon library

Tags: android, python-2.7, ibeacon, altbeacon, raspberry-pi3

I have [python script](https://github.com/dburr/linux-ibeacon) which transmits beacon. I executed script on raspberry pi. Now I want to locate beacon on android device. I have created a app using android-beacon-library. Now as per the documentation I should set beacon parser to locate beacon. I found so many arctilces saying search for "setBeaconLayout" on google. I tried everything to find out right expression but I am not able to find it out the correct expression. Where I can find correct expression or any hint to create my own expression.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319682/correct-layout-to-detect-kontakt-beacon-on-android-with-altbeacon)

[image]

The byte offsets in the beaconLayout string start with the manufacturer data.

Correct beacon layout is m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24