# Radius Network Beacon Library 2.0 (AltBeacon) unable to detect Beacons

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, altbeacon

Hello I'm currently using Radius Network Beacon SDK but unable to detect my beacons.
In didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection beacons, Region region) collection object size is 0

Please help me!!

RangingActivity Code-

```
import java.util.Collection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.AltBeacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;

public class RangingActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer {
  protected static final String TAG = "RangingActivity";
private BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ranging);

    beaconManager.bind(this);
    beaconManager.debug = true;
}
@Override 
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}
@Override 
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
@Override 
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
    @Override 
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        if (beacons.size() > 0) {
            EditText editText = (EditText)RangingActivity.this
                    .findViewById(R.id.rangingText);
            Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
            logToDisplay("The first beacon "+firstBeacon.toString()+" is about "+firstBeacon.getDistance()+" meters away.");
        }
    }



    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        //beaconManager.updateScanPeriods();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
}
private void logToDisplay(final String line) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            EditText editText = (EditText)RangingActivity.this
                    .findViewById(R.id.rangingText);
            editText.append(line+"\n");             
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: where from u add the library android project.. Have u added that?

Comment: which beacon you are using?
according to AltBeacon library,
**IMPORTANT: By default, this library will only detect beacons meeting the new AltBeacon specification.**

Comment: I just follow all instruction provided by Altbeacon...bu no luck

Comment: I am using BlueCat and Kontakt Beacons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a custom Parser to properly recognize that beacons.

Take a look at this answer:

[Is this the correct layout to detect iBeacons with AltBeacon's Android Beacon Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027983/is-this-the-correct-layout-to-detect-ibeacons-with-altbeacons-android-beacon-li)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `onBeaconConnect()` in your `onCreate` function

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_ranging);

  beaconManager.bind(this);
  beaconManager.debug = true;

  onBeaconConnect()
}
```