# Using AltBeacon

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I'd like to use the AltBeacon Library to detect the RadBeacon Tag from Radius Networks. To understand how the library works I'd like to use the reference application of AltBeacon.

I implemented [this code](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) in my sample app. After adding the AltBeacon Library into the project I can run the project.

Like I mentioned before I' like to detect the IBeacons RadBeacon Tag from Radius Networks. I know that I need to use the BeaconParser. My Question is how the BeaconParser for  RadBeacon Tag look like. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027983/is-this-the-correct-layout-to-detect-ibeacons-with-altbeacons-android-beacon-li) is a IBeacon Parser for Estimote Beacons.
When I debug this project and look inside of the logcat I can see the following messages:

```
"Beacon detected: id1: "UUID of RadBeacon" id2= "Major of RadBeacon" id3:"Minor of RadBeacon"".
"looking for ranging region mathes for this beacon"
"got record"
"This is not a matching Beacon advertisment."
```

How do i need to change the BeaconParser? Here is my source code

```
public class FindRadBeaconActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements BeaconConsumer{
private BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
protected static final String TAG = "RangingActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_rad_beacon);

    // check bluetooth
    verifyBluetooth();

    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    beaconManager.debug = true;
    beaconManager.bind(this);

}

@Override 
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.find_rad_beacon, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
      Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");       
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
      Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);      
    }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
}

private void verifyBluetooth() {

    try {
        if (!BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).checkAvailability()) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Bluetooth not enabled");          
            builder.setMessage("Please enable bluetooth in settings and restart this application.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);                 
                }                   
            });
            builder.show();
        }           
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Bluetooth LE not available");         
        builder.setMessage("Sorry, this device does not support Bluetooth LE.");
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);                 
            }

        });
        builder.show();

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for RadBeacon Layout, use the below layout

```
mBeaconManager
            .getBeaconParsers()
            .add(new BeaconParser()
                    .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
```