# Cannot detect iBeacon using AltBeacon/android-beacon-library

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

Currently, I am working on a project using an android phone to detect iBeacons and read/write the uuid, major minor etc information from iBeacon

After searching on the web, it seems that AltBeacon/android-beacon-library is recommended to use for detecting the iBeacons. However, I cant find any result of iBeacons when I try the sample code of the the following link-http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html or I run the sample reference app-https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference . I have download an app called "**Locate**" from Google Play developed by **Radius Networks** and it aslo cannot find my iBeacon.

All above ways fail to show the iBeacons result. When I try debug on it, functions like didRangeBeaconsInRegion(), didEnterRegion(), didExitRegion() never be called.

However from logcat I find some device information:

> 10-24 13:56:31.878: D/BluetoothAdapter(14042): onScanResult() -
>   Device=20:CD:39:80:60:F7 RSSI=-70

I have tested that my iBeacons should be ok with the app - **iBeacon Detector** and it can detect my iBeacon.

Did I miss some steps? Or this library is not suitable for my development? Please comment.

I am quite new to Android development and iBeacons, please let me know if you need additional requirement. Thanks for you help.

Comment: are you sure you beacon works?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think my beacon works. I setup a new beacon layout and the reference application works finally. There are details from another post - [Is this the correct layout to detect iBeacons with AltBeacon's Android Beacon Library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027983/is-this-the-correct-layout-to-detect-ibeacons-with-altbeacons-android-beacon-li)

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.flurp.beaconscanner.app 
this app allowed me to detect an iBeacon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm trying to do the same thing as you did. And I also want to use AltBeacon/android-beacon-library, but I haven't done it yet, answer below is my guess, hope it can give you some clue.

I think your problem might be the misuse of the library.

According to the home page of Android-beacon-library http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html, it says,

> By default, it will only detect beacons meeting the open AltBeacon
>   standard. If you wish to configure the library to work with different
>   types of beacons, see the documentation for the BeaconParser class.

iBeacon is a beacon standard different from the open AltBeacon standard used in the Android-beacon-library, so if you want your app using the Android-beacon-library to detect an iBeacon device, you have to implement the BeaconParser which can parser messages conforming to iBeacon standard.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and that's a great clue. I will try it and update the post later.

Comment: You are correct. All I need to do is just change the layout of beacon. [link](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconParser.html#setBeaconLayout(java.lang.String))

Comment: This is correct.  Understand that to keep the library open source it cannot be pre-configured to detect proprietary beacon formats.  But it is very easy to add a custom `BeaconParser` to decode any proprietary beacon format using a single line of code.  Simply do a Google search for "getBeaconParsers" (include the quotes) to see how other folks have done this.

Comment: @davidgyoung, does this mean that Android beacon library is enough to detect almost all or all beacons from various manufactures ( I'm using smartbeacon and kontakt.io beacon)?

Comment: Yes, provided that you supply a BeaconParser for these, which I believe use the proprietary iBeacon format.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to do this:

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
       setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
```

For more information, refer to [Is this the correct layout to detect iBeacons with AltBeacon's Android Beacon Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25027983/122441)