# Kontakt beacon how to retrieve beacon based on accuracy

Tags: ibeacon-android

I need to scan when the beacons are near but what I need is that the beacon that gets find is the nearest not a random one.
I tried with both methods:

```
public void onBeaconsUpdated(final Region region, final List<BeaconDevice> beacons) {
            for(int i=0; i<beacons.size();i++)
            {
                beacon = beacons.get(i);
                if(beacon.getProximity() != Proximity.UNKNOWN && beacon.getAccuracy() < 4)
                {
                    i = beacons.size() + 1;
                }
            }//THIS IS THE METHOD I USE TO GET THE NEAREST BEACON FROM THE LIST BUT IT DOESN'T WORK

                if(beacon.getMinor() == 1 && beacon.getMinor() != lastBeacon)
                {
                }
                if(beacon.getMinor() == 2 && beacon.getMinor() != lastBeacon)
                {
                }
                if(beacon.getMinor() == 3 && beacon.getMinor() != lastBeacon)
                {
                }
                if(beacon.getMinor() == 4 && beacon.getMinor() != lastBeacon)
                {
                }
                if(beacon.getMinor() == 5 && beacon.getMinor() != lastBeacon)
                {
                }
//and so on
    }

@Override
public void onBeaconAppeared(final Region region, final BeaconDevice beacon) {
}
```

For the first method the list is not ordered based on the accuracy,
On the second method the beacon gets found not based on their accuracy.
Is it possible for the first method to order the list in order to have the NEAREST beacon?

**EDIT:** I also have another problem, when I find a beacon i'd like to stop monitoring for other but calling `beaconManager.stopMonitoring();` doesn't work and the app keeps searching for beacons.. is it the correct method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the BeaconManager's configuration part, set [BeaconDevice.DistanceSort](http://kontaktio.github.io/Android-SDK/Javadoc/com/kontakt/sdk/android/device/BeaconDevice.DistanceSort.html), with [ASC](http://kontaktio.github.io/Android-SDK/Javadoc/com/kontakt/sdk/android/device/BeaconDevice.DistanceSort.html#ASC) value please.

```
 BeaconManager.setDistanceSort(DistanceSort.ASC);
```

You can then easily retrieve Beacon instance from the list by specifying:

```
  ublic void onBeaconsUpdated(final Region region, final List<BeaconDevice> beacons) {
        final BeaconDevice beaconDevice = beacons.get(0); // the nearest beacon device.
}
```

I see as well that you're interested in `lastBeacon` minor value and several major values. You can as well apply filter that will handle the acceptance only of the Beacons with the `lastBeacon` minor value and several major values. You can do it with MinorFilter, MajorFilter and CustomFilter.

**If 0 beacons are nearby the method public void `onMonitorStop()` gets called, is there any way to prevent this method to get called and keep scanning?**

Both `onMonitorStart()` and `onMonitorStop()` are tightly bound to the [MonitorPeriod](http://kontaktio.github.io/Android-SDK/Javadoc/com/kontakt/sdk/android/configuration/MonitorPeriod.html). The [MonitorPeriod.getActivePeriod()](http://kontaktio.github.io/Android-SDK/Javadoc/com/kontakt/sdk/android/configuration/MonitorPeriod.html#getActivePeriod--) specifies how long monitoring lasts and [MonitorPeriod.getPassivePeriod()](http://kontaktio.github.io/Android-SDK/Javadoc/com/kontakt/sdk/android/configuration/MonitorPeriod.html#getPassivePeriod--) tells how long the Android device is inactive between 2 following active periods.

I see that you're interested in `onBeaconsUpdated()` method mostly so you could alternatively register [RangingListener](http://kontaktio.github.io/Android-SDK/Javadoc/com/kontakt/sdk/android/manager/BeaconManager.RangingListener.html) as it provides single method where you get Region and list of the devices.

Ranging employs a bit less resources than monitoring and is preferable if you are focused on the remote devices rather than regions entering/abandoning.

Comment: Yes using `BeaconManager.setDistanceSort(DistanceSort.ASC);` worked!
Thank you thank you thank you very much!!!
  Sorry if I stress you but if possible I have one last question, if 0 beacons are nearby the method `public void onMonitorStop()` gets called, is there any way to prevent this method to get called and keep scanning?

Comment: Thank you, you're really helpful! If possible is there any way I can contact you? Because I still have some questions left if you have any time. Again thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: If you have any further questions, please ask them here (https://github.com/kontaktio/Android-SDK). Just raise an issue, we regularily answer questions concerning the SDKs .
There is also a sample application project (https://github.com/kontaktio/kontakt-beacon-admin-sample-app). If you want the SDK to do things that you're up to in your app, just raise the issue with your use-case, we'll try to figure out how to help you, thanks.