# iBeacon android app

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am busy with transmitting a Bluetooth Low Energy UUID via my Raspberry Pi. That setup is done and works to a satisfactory extent.

But now my personal objective is to make a very simple android app, that catches this UUID and displays it on the android screen.

So after some browsing around, I found this Radius Network iBeacon package with a iBeacon.java code in it.

I am very new to Android Studio. For the life of me, I can't seem to debug that iBeacon.java code to my android (Jellybean) phone..

So basically the directory for that code looks like this:

*android-ibeacon-service/src/com/radiusnetworks/ibeacon/client/iBeacon.java*

I guess the first directory part is the package?

I have tried importing the whole thing, but it shows so many things not working,
I have also tried just importing the iBeacon.java code.. But that doesn't run to my phone..

The iBeacon.java looks like this:

```
/**
 * Radius Networks, Inc.
 * http://www.radiusnetworks.com
 * 
 * @author David G. Young
 * 
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
package com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon;

import java.util.Collections;

import com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.client.RangedIBeacon;

import android.util.Log;

/**
* The <code>IBeacon</code> class represents a single hardware iBeacon detected by 
* an Android device.
* 
* <pre>An iBeacon is identified by a three part identifier based on the fields
* proximityUUID - a string UUID typically identifying the owner of a
*                 number of ibeacons
* major - a 16 bit integer indicating a group of iBeacons
* minor - a 16 bit integer identifying a single iBeacon</pre>
*
* An iBeacon sends a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) advertisement that contains these
* three identifiers, along with the calibrated tx power (in RSSI) of the 
* iBeacon's Bluetooth transmitter.  
* 
* This class may only be instantiated from a BLE packet, and an RSSI measurement for
* the packet.  The class parses out the three part identifier, along with the calibrated
* tx power.  It then uses the measured RSSI and calibrated tx power to do a rough
* distance measurement (the accuracy field) and group it into a more reliable buckets of 
* distance (the proximity field.)
* 
* @author  David G. Young
* @see     Region#matchesIBeacon(IBeacon iBeacon)
*/
public class IBeacon { 
    /**
     * Less than half a meter away
     */
    public static final int PROXIMITY_IMMEDIATE = 1;
    /**
     * More than half a meter away, but less than four meters away
     */
    public static final int PROXIMITY_NEAR = 2;
    /**
     * More than four meters away
     */
    public static final int PROXIMITY_FAR = 3;
    /**
     * No distance estimate was possible due to a bad RSSI value or measured TX power
     */
    public static final int PROXIMITY_UNKNOWN = 0;

    final private static char[] hexArray = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'};
    private static final String TAG = "IBeacon";    

    /**
     * A 16 byte UUID that typically represents the company owning a number of iBeacons
     * Example: E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0 
     */
    protected String proximityUuid;
    /**
     * A 16 bit integer typically used to represent a group of iBeacons
     */
    protected int major;
    /**
     * A 16 bit integer that identifies a specific iBeacon within a group 
     */
    protected int minor;
    /**
     * An integer with four possible values representing a general idea of how far the iBeacon is away
     * @see #PROXIMITY_IMMEDIATE
     * @see #PROXIMITY_NEAR
     * @see #PROXIMITY_FAR
     * @see #PROXIMITY_UNKNOWN
     */
    protected Integer proximity;
    /**
     * A double that is an estimate of how far the iBeacon is away in meters.  This name is confusing, but is copied from
     * the iOS7 SDK terminology.   Note that this number fluctuates quite a bit with RSSI, so despite the name, it is not
     * super accurate.   It is recommended to instead use the proximity field, or your own bucketization of this value. 
     */
    protected Double accuracy;
    /**
     * The measured signal strength of the Bluetooth packet that led do this iBeacon detection.
     */
    protected int rssi;
    /**
     * The calibrated measured Tx power of the iBeacon in RSSI
     * This value is baked into an iBeacon when it is manufactured, and
     * it is transmitted with each packet to aid in the distance estimate
     */
    protected int txPower;

    /**
     * If multiple RSSI samples were available, this is the running average
     */
    protected Double runningAverageRssi = null;

    /**
     * @see #accuracy
     * @return accuracy
     */
    public double getAccuracy() {
        if (accuracy == null) {
            accuracy = calculateAccuracy(txPower, runningAverageRssi != null ? runningAverageRssi : rssi );     
        }
        return accuracy;
    }
    /**
     * @see #major
     * @return major
     */
    public int getMajor() {
        return major;
    }
    /**
     * @see #minor
     * @return minor
     */
    public int getMinor() {
        return minor;
    }
    /**
     * @see #proximity
     * @return proximity
     */
    public int getProximity() {
        if (proximity == null) {
            proximity = calculateProximity(getAccuracy());      
        }
        return proximity;       
    }
    /**
     * @see #rssi
     * @return rssi
     */
    public int getRssi() {
        return rssi;
    }
    /**
     * @see #txPower
     * @return txPowwer
     */
    public int getTxPower() {
        return txPower;
    }

    /**
     * @see #proximityUuid
     * @return proximityUuid
     */
    public String getProximityUuid() {
        return proximityUuid;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return minor;
    }

    /**
     * Two detected iBeacons are considered equal if they share the same three identifiers, regardless of their distance or RSSI.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (!(that instanceof IBeacon)) {
            return false;
        }
        IBeacon thatIBeacon = (IBeacon) that;       
        return (thatIBeacon.getMajor() == this.getMajor() && thatIBeacon.getMinor() == this.getMinor() && thatIBeacon.getProximityUuid() == thatIBeacon.getProximityUuid());
    }
    /**
     * Construct an iBeacon from a Bluetooth LE packet collected by Android's Bluetooth APIs
     * 
     * @param scanData The actual packet bytes
     * @param rssi The measured signal strength of the packet
     * @return An instance of an <code>IBeacon</code>
     */
    public static IBeacon fromScanData(byte[] scanData, int rssi) {


        if (((int)scanData[5] & 0xff) == 0x4c &&
            ((int)scanData[6] & 0xff) == 0x00 &&
            ((int)scanData[7] & 0xff) == 0x02 &&
            ((int)scanData[8] & 0xff) == 0x15) {            
            // yes!  This is an iBeacon     
        }



        else if (((int)scanData[5] & 0xff) == 0x2d &&
                ((int)scanData[6] & 0xff) == 0x24 &&
                ((int)scanData[7] & 0xff) == 0xbf &&
                ((int)scanData[8] & 0xff) == 0x16) {    
            // this is an Estimote beacon
            IBeacon iBeacon = new IBeacon();
            iBeacon.major = 0;
            iBeacon.minor = 0;
            iBeacon.proximityUuid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
            iBeacon.txPower = -55;
            return iBeacon;
        }       
        else {
            // This is not an iBeacon
            Log.d(TAG, "This is not an iBeacon advertisment.  The bytes I see are: "+bytesToHex(scanData));
            return null;
        }

        IBeacon iBeacon = new IBeacon();

        iBeacon.major = (scanData[25] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanData[26] & 0xff);
        iBeacon.minor = (scanData[27] & 0xff) * 0x100 + (scanData[28] & 0xff);
        iBeacon.txPower = (int)scanData[29]; // this one is signed
        iBeacon.rssi = rssi;

        // AirLocate:
        // 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15  # Apple's fixed iBeacon advertising prefix
        // e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 48 d2 b0 60 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 # iBeacon profile uuid
        // 00 00 # major 
        // 00 00 # minor 
        // c5 # The 2's complement of the calibrated Tx Power
        // Estimote:        
        // 02 01 1a 11 07 2d 24 bf 16 
        // 394b31ba3f486415ab376e5c0f09457374696d6f7465426561636f6e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

        byte[] proximityUuidBytes = new byte[16];
        System.arraycopy(scanData, 9, proximityUuidBytes, 0, 16); 
        String hexString = bytesToHex(proximityUuidBytes);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(hexString.substring(0,8));
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(hexString.substring(8,12));
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(hexString.substring(12,16));
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(hexString.substring(16,20));
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(hexString.substring(20,32));
        iBeacon.proximityUuid = sb.toString();

        return iBeacon;
    }

    protected IBeacon(IBeacon otherIBeacon) {
        this.major = otherIBeacon.major;
        this.minor = otherIBeacon.minor;
        this.accuracy = otherIBeacon.accuracy;
        this.proximity = otherIBeacon.proximity;
        this.rssi = otherIBeacon.rssi;
        this.proximityUuid = otherIBeacon.proximityUuid;
        this.txPower = otherIBeacon.txPower;
    }

    protected IBeacon() {

    }

    protected static double calculateAccuracy(int txPower, double rssi) {
        if (rssi == 0) {
            return -1.0; // if we cannot determine accuracy, return -1.
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "calculating accuracy based on rssi of "+rssi);


        double ratio = rssi*1.0/txPower;
        if (ratio < 1.0) {
            return Math.pow(ratio,10);
        }
        else {
            double accuracy =  (0.89976)*Math.pow(ratio,7.7095) + 0.111;    
            Log.d(TAG, " avg rssi: "+rssi+" accuracy: "+accuracy);
            return accuracy;
        }
    }   

    protected static int calculateProximity(double accuracy) {
        if (accuracy < 0) {
            return PROXIMITY_UNKNOWN;    
            // is this correct?  does proximity only show unknown when accuracy is negative?  I have seen cases where it returns unknown when
            // accuracy is -1;
        }
        if (accuracy < 0.5 ) {
            return IBeacon.PROXIMITY_IMMEDIATE;
        }
        // forums say 3.0 is the near/far threshold, but it looks to be based on experience that this is 4.0
        if (accuracy <= 4.0) { 
            return IBeacon.PROXIMITY_NEAR;
        }
        // if it is > 4.0 meters, call it far
        return IBeacon.PROXIMITY_FAR;

    }

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        int v;
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    } 
}
```

How can I solve this mystery? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the one who wrote that IBeacon.java code about two years ago.  Since then it has been rewritten and is now available in a ready to run Android Studio reference app here:

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference

You do have to make one change to it to get it to detect iBeacons.  See here for that change:

[Is this the correct layout to detect iBeacons with AltBeacon's Android Beacon Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027983/is-this-the-correct-layout-to-detect-ibeacons-with-altbeacons-android-beacon-li)

Comment: So I Downloaded Gradle, I referred the local.properties to the right sdk directory. Than I opened Android Studio. I clicked import project, than I chose android-beacon-library-reference. I referred to the Gradle home folder and it imported everything for me. However I can't (debug or) run anything. And then I went to look at the second link about the layout. But which of the code needs the have the Public Class MainActivity alteration?

Comment: I would go through a couple of tutorials on Android Studio until you get the basics of  running apps on your phone: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: Problem solved.. I knew it wasn't my fault. I tried the exact same thing on a friends laptop (who has WINDOWS) and everything imported correctly I added Main Activity and now all is well :)  Somehow the project can't import correctly on an Apple Mac..