# How can i uniquely identify an iBeacon using android ALT Beacon library?

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I have made my iphone 4s an iBeacon and able to detect this using Locate Beacon app from my Glaxy S4, 5.01, I have also detected this using [beacon reference library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) by modifying its layout found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027983/is-this-the-correct-layout-to-detect-ibeacons-with-altbeacons-android-beacon-li). Its showing the detect beacon in device logs from the library files as below,

onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=6C:64:80:68:86:59, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=26, mServiceUuids=null, mManufacturerSpecificData={76=[2, 21, -96, -54, 104, -88, 101, -76, 75, 30, -66, -91, 73, -91, -114, -5, -124, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0, -59]}, mServiceData={}, mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=null], mRssi=-46, mTimestampNanos=162979288294680}

i am getting device name always null, and also unable to get the uuid, and i can't get that in my application, can any one please help how can i get beacon info in my application ?

Also How can i uniquely identify a beacon?

Here's what i have done so far, downloaded a ALT beacon library, then ALT beacon library reference, added library dependency, and written the following code in Ranging Activity class,

modified the onCreate method as

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ranging);
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
              setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));  // iBeacons
    beaconManager.bind(this);

}
```

and implements this by BeaconConsumer, and added his method as

```
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override 
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about "+beacons.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");        
            }
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {  e.printStackTrace();  }
}
```

if i run the code without,

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
              setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));  // iBeacons
```

then it works fine when add this statement get exception as mentioned before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i am able to identify my problem, my beacon parser was wrong

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
```

i was using this while i correct results that detects an ibeacon for me are given by this parser

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser(). setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using beacon Monitoring when you really want to be using beacon Ranging.  Monitoring is used to tell you when any one of a group of beacons with shared identifier parts (or any beacon at all) is first detected.  But it doesn't tell you the exact identifiers of the beacons in view.

In order to read the identifiers of beacons that are visible at a given time, you should use the Ranging APIs.  These APIs give you a callback to your code once per second with a list of all visible beacons matching the Region you define.

```
@Override 
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
     for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {
        Log.i(TAG, "I see a beacon with identifiers: "+beacon.getId1()+" "+beacon.getId2()+" "+beacon.getId3());        
     }
}
```

See the [Ranging Example Code on this page](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) for more details on how to set this up.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i really do admire your great work for beacons especially, 

I have followed Ranging Example Code as well in the  beacon reference library code, but that throughs an exception as 
"06-19 14:28:58.611: E/AndroidRuntime(23645): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
06-19 14:28:58.611: E/AndroidRuntime(23645):  at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:928)
" 
and this caused, when i add beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")); line.

Comment: You need to add the beaconParser before you do anything else with the library.  Put it in the first line after you get an instance of the beaconManager.  For your other exception, please show two code excerpts of what causes the exception (1) the initial setup where you set the beacon parser and (2) your didRangeBeaconsInRegion method.

Comment: i have edit the question, please check. Thanks for your valuable tim.

Comment: The issue is that the beacon parser needs to be added when the beaconManager is first constructed.  Since you are using the reference application, this must happen in the BeaconReferenceApplication.onCreate method **NOT** the RangingActivity.onCreate method

Comment: I have written the same code in BeaconReferenceApplication.onCreate but didRangeBeaconsInRegion never calls :( i am detecting the iBeacon using locate app in ipad, beacon detection is shown in logcat but no response in code.

Comment: I am only talking about the beacon parser.  Move that to the BraconReferenceApplication class.  You can leave the ranging code where it is.

Comment: also tried this, i have added this
mBeaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
      setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")); 
while in ranging activity 
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.bind(this);
but still no detections, i will be grateful if you can refer some working code,  i just need to detect an ibeacon from my android s4 5.0.1 device. Thanks

Comment: Sorry you are having trouble -- it should be very simple!  Just start over with a clean copy of the reference app, then replace [this line](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beaconreference/BeaconReferenceApplication.java#L41) with your parser expression shown above.

Comment: m really stuck at this, i have tried multiple times with new project, is there any possibility of problem with my devices ? I make an Ibeacon using locate app from iPad, that while i detect by locate app in android s4, it detects this as ibeacon. But not working while i write my own code.

Comment: Perhaps it is a device or beacon-specific problem with the latest version of the library, yes.  Please try running this test version of the reference app, follow the instructions, and let me know that you see.  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference/releases/tag/adhoc1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your timely response and support, finally i am able to identify my problem, my beacon parser was wrong         beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")); i was using this while i correct results are given by this         beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24")); Thanks again

Comment: Glad you figured it out!  Would you mind taking the results of your last comment and putting it into an answer of your own and accepting it?  That way other folks who find this question will easily see what you did to fix the problem.