# android beacon library not start detecting beacons

Tags: java, android, mobile, ibeacon, altbeacon

I don't know where is the problem with my code, I'm trying to detect beacon using https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library
sorry for bad English and I'm new in mobile application development.

AndroidManifiets.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.isleem.hospital">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.BeaconApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".activities.BeaconActivity"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

BeaconActivity.class

```
package com.isleem.hospital.activities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;


import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;

import java.util.Collection;

public class BeaconActivity extends Activity implements  BeaconConsumer  {
    protected static final String TAG = "RangingActivity";
    private BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("naji","beaconactivity");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        RangeNotifier rangeNotifier = new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion called with beacon count:  "+beacons.size());
                    Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                    Log.d("naji","The first beacon " + firstBeacon.toString() + " is about " + firstBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away.");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "no avilable beacons");
                }
            }
        };
        try {
//            Collection<Region> monitoredRegions = beaconManager.getMonitoredRegions();
//           Log.d("monitoredRegions",monitoredRegions.toString());
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId",null,null,null));
            beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

BeaconApplication.class

```
package com.isleem.hospital.application;

import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;

import com.isleem.hospital.R;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap;

public class BeaconApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
    private static final String TAG = "BeaconReferenceApp";
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
    private boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;
    private String cumulativeLog = "";
    BeaconManager beaconManager ;
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.setDebug(false);
        beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        builder.setContentTitle("Scanning for Beacons");
        beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.getNotification(),0);
        beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);
        Log.d(TAG, "setting up background monitoring for beacons and power saving");
        Region region = new Region("myRangingUniqueId",
            null, null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
//        try {
//            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
//        } catch (RemoteException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }


}


    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        // In this example, this class sends a notification to the user whenever a Beacon
        // matching a Region (defined above) are first seen.
        Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");
        if (!haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity");

            // The very first time since boot that we detect an beacon, we launch the
            // MainActivity
            //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class);
            //   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            // Important:  make sure to add android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the manifest
            // to keep multiple copies of this activity from getting created if the user has
            // already manually launched the app.
            //   this.startActivity(intent);
            haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = true;
        } else {
            // If the Monitoring Activity is visible, we log info about the beacons we have
            // seen on its display
            Log.d("beacon","I see a beacon again" );
            // If we have already seen beacons before, but the monitoring activity is not in
            // the foreground, we send a notification to the user on subsequent detections.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        Log.d(TAG,"I no longer see a beacon.");
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Current region state is: " + (state == 1 ? "INSIDE" : "OUTSIDE ("+state+")"));
    }


}
```

and i use this code to start my BeaconActivity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, BeaconActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check:

1. Is your beacon advertising?  Try an off-the-shelf app like [BeaconScope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner&hl=en_US) and make sure it is detected.
2. Did you dynamically [request and obtain location permission](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html) from the user?  You cannot detect beacons unless you do so.
3. Did you set a BeaconParser for the type of beacon you are using?  If using AltBeacon you don't need to do this.  But [if using iBeacon you do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25049827/1461050).
4. Do you get a call to "didDetermineStateForRegion"?  Does it say you are already inside the region?  If so, it may be that your beacon is detected, but the library thinks it is already in the region (it remembers this across restarts) so it never calls didEnterRegion again.
5. Is bluetooth on?  Is location turn on in phone settings?  If you check app permissions does it confirm that location permission has been granted to your app?

Comment: 1- yes the app can see my beacon
2- yes the permission was requested and I approved to access my location.
3- no I didn't set I will check if its the problem or not.
4- i think the beacon detection was not started because i didn't see any logs 
5- yes, and i kicked the user if not running

thanks for replaying and sorry again for bad english

Comment: Thank you the problem is i didn't add beacon layout in BeaconParser . and i remove duplicate code in BeaconApplication.class
beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);