# How to implement iBeacon on PSoC 4 BLE from Cypress?

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, psoc

From [What is the iBeacon Bluetooth Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906988/what-is-the-ibeacon-bluetooth-profile) I understood the format of iBeacon. In [Project #008: GAP Broadcaster](http://www.cypress.com/?rid=107903) it is mentioned that iBeacon is based on GAP Broadcaster approach. However, PSoC Creator doesn't allow me to customize advertisement packet to make iBeacon based on GAP Broadcaster template. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new adv type packet and use the API CyBle_GapUpdateAdvData() to update advertisement data.
Try the project at:
https://github.com/cypresssemiconductorco/PSoC-4-BLE/tree/master/100_Projects_in_100_Days/Day009_Dynamic_Broadcaster