# Beacon Payload Analysis

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon, analysis, traffic, tshark

I am analyzing the traffic beacons generate using tshark and iptraf. I know they are mainly used to determine the proximity of a device and like any other network device the traffic generated by them must be having a header and payload information in it.

What is best way to find out the payload information though header info can be identified as to where packet is being sent etc , but how we can classify the payload and what information it contains in a beacon signal , is it the same like any other web traffic sent and receive on a network or is it different since they make use of Bluetooth ?

Any pointers regarding would be useful .

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth LE beacon transmissions are much simpler than the HTTP protocol.  They are transmit only and have no real headers, although there are short segments within the transmissions called PDUs that have a similar purpose.

To see an example of a beacon transmission, see my answer here:
[What is the iBeacon Bluetooth Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906988/what-is-the-ibeacon-bluetooth-profile)

Comment: thanks for the info I got some start now, as i understand from the link you posted about ibeacon profile, PDU is about 2-40 bytes in size which can further be divided in two main categories " advertising channel PDU " and " data channel PDU " each of which has a " header and payload " , so I have trouble understanding I did broadcasting or advertised data from my raspbery pi bluetooth dongle connected to it following one of the tutorials , is it possible to analyse specifically the payload part of PDU  using wireshark or any of the available tools ?