# How to broadcast iBeacon with the BluetoothLeScanner class?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android

I want to transmit iBluetooth over android with the [BluetoothLeAdvertiser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html) class from [android.bluetooth.le](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/package-summary.html). But it seems I can't set some of the **Manufacturer spec data** fields to match those of the iBeacon.


**iBeacon structure**:
[image: iBeacon data packet]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906988/what-is-the-ibeacon-bluetooth-profile) and [this](http://smlie-blog.blogspot.com/2014/06/bluetooth-ibeacon-packet-format.html) tell you what an iBeacon's **Manufacturer spec data** values need to contain. Basically:

```
Apple Company Identifier (Little Endian), 0x004c = 76
data type, 0x02 => iBeacon
data length, 0x15 = 21
uuid: 585CDE931B0142CC9A1325009BEDC65E
major: [0000]
minor: 0000
meaured power at 1 meter: 0xc5 = -59
```

---

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-04-16-build-android-ibeacon-beacon-emitter/) that has these steps:

1. Create the [AdvertiseData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.html) object using [AdvertiseData.Builder.addManufacturerData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html#addManufacturerData(int,%20byte[])) (which I believe should be the **Manufacturer spec data**, see below for the issues with that)

   ```
   protected void setAdvertiseData() {

     AdvertiseData.Builder mBuilder = new AdvertiseData.Builder();

     ByteBuffer mManufacturerData = ByteBuffer.allocate(24);

     byte[] uuid = getIdAsByte(UUID.fromString("0CF052C2-97CA-407C-84F8-B62AAC4E9020"));

     mManufacturerData.put(0, (byte)0xBE); // Beacon Identifier

     mManufacturerData.put(1, (byte)0xAC); // Beacon Identifier

     for (int i=2; i<=17; i++) {

       mManufacturerData.put(i, uuid[i-2]); // adding the UUID

     }

     mManufacturerData.put(18, (byte)0x00); // first byte of Major
     mManufacturerData.put(19, (byte)0x09); // second byte of Major
     mManufacturerData.put(20, (byte)0x00); // first minor
     mManufacturerData.put(21, (byte)0x06); // second minor
     mManufacturerData.put(22, (byte)0xB5); // txPower
     mBuilder.addManufacturerData(224, mManufacturerData.array()); // using google's company ID
     mAdvertiseData = mBuilder.build();
   }
   ```
2. Create [AdvertiseSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.html) using the [AdvertiseSettings.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.Builder.html#AdvertiseSettings.Builder())

   ```
   protected void setAdvertiseSettings() {
     AdvertiseSettings.Builder mBuilder = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder();
     mBuilder.setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_POWER);
     mBuilder.setConnectable(false);
     mBuilder.setTimeout(0);
     mBuilder.setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_MEDIUM);
     mAdvertiseSettings = mBuilder.build();
   }
   ```
3. Broadcast the AdvertiseSettings and AdvertiseData using  [BluetoothLeAdvertiser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html). (This also takes a callBack that tells if Bluetooth transmission worked, no problems there)

   ```
   mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(mAdvertiseSettings, mAdvertiseData, mAdvertiseCallback);
   ```

---

The problem with these steps are:

- It's not clear where [AdvertiseData.Builder.addManufacturerData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html#addManufacturerData(int,%20byte[])) is putting its second Byte[] manufacturerSpecificData parameter in terms of the **Manufacturer spec data**, especially because the first parameter of [AdvertiseData.Builder.addManufacturerData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html#addManufacturerData(int,%20byte[])) is also the *Manufacturer Type* field in the **Manufacturer spec data**
- The following [BluetoothLeAdvertiser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html) constructor parameters seem to write bytes to the **Manufacturer spec data**, overwriting the Bytes added in addManufacturerData

  - [AdvertiseSettings.Builder.setTxPowerLevel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.Builder.html#setTxPowerLevel(int)) and [PeriodicAdvertisingParameters.Builder.setIncludeTxPower](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/PeriodicAdvertisingParameters.Builder.html#setIncludeTxPower(boolean)) would overwrite the TX power (RSSI) set in [AdvertiseData.Builder.addManufacturerData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html#addManufacturerData(int,%20byte[])) and would overwrite each other when combined in some of the other [BluetoothLeAdvertiser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html) functions like [BluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertisingSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html#startAdvertisingSet(android.bluetooth.le.AdvertisingSetParameters,%20android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData,%20android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData,%20android.bluetooth.le.PeriodicAdvertisingParameters,%20android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData,%20android.bluetooth.le.AdvertisingSetCallback)).
  - Although it's not shown in the example I gave, [AdvertiseData.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html#addServiceUuid(android.os.ParcelUuid))  also has the function [addServiceUuid](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html#addServiceUuid(android.os.ParcelUuid)) which would overwrite the UUID added in [AdvertiseData.Builder.addManufacturerData()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseData.Builder.html#addManufacturerData(int,%20byte[]))

---

At first I was following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-advertise-android-as-a-bluetooth-le-peripheral--cms-25426) tutorial, and was transmitting an Alt-Beacon. Perhaps the [BluetoothLeAdvertiser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.html) class is assuming I'm still transmitting Alt-Beacon which is differently structured than iBeacons.


**Alt-Beacon structure**:[image: Alt-Beacon Data packet]

other resources:

- [ti docs on BLE](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/swra475a/swra475a.pdf)
- [decompiled source for all these functions](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser.java#BluetoothLeAdvertiser.AdvertiseCallbackWrapper.0mBluetoothGatt)
- [Android Bluetooth Low Energy tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

**updated code**

```
public AdvertiseData getiBeaconData() {
    AdvertiseData.Builder mBuilder = new AdvertiseData.Builder();
    ByteBuffer mManufacturerData = ByteBuffer.allocate(24);

    byte[] uuid = getIdAsByte(UUID.fromString(thisCont.getString( R.string.ble_uuid )) );
    ParcelUuid parced = new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString(thisCont.getString( R.string.ble_uuid )) );
    /*
```

R.string.ble_uuid == CDB7950D-73F1-4D4D-8E47-C090502DBD63
        this is about the iBeacon structure
        http://smlie-blog.blogspot.com/2014/06/bluetooth-ibeacon-packet-format.html
         */

```
    //mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x00); //Manufactor Id 1
    //mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x4C); //Manufactor Id 2
   // mManufacturerData.put((byte)0xBE); //ibeconid1
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x02); //ibeconid2
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x15); //Data length
    for (byte i:uuid) {
        mManufacturerData.put(i); // adding the UUID
    }
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x00); //major first
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x00); //major second
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x00); //minor first
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x00); //minor second
    //mManufacturerData.put((byte)0xC5); //TX power

    /*
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x1A); // Beacon Identifier was BE  iBeacon = 00
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0xFF); // Beacon Identifier was AC  iBeacon = 02
    /* the above 2 lines are the ibeacon AD Indicator

    for (byte i:uuid) {
        mManufacturerData.put(i); // adding the UUID
    }
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x00); // first byte of Major
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x00); // second byte of Major
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x00); // first minor
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0x00); // second minor
    mManufacturerData.put((byte)0xC5); // txPower (RSSI) (from tx)
    mBuilder.addManufacturerData(16, mManufacturerData.array()); // using google's company ID
    */

    mBuilder.addManufacturerData(76, mManufacturerData.array()); // using google's company ID
    //mBuilder.addServiceUuid(parced);
    return mBuilder.build();

}
```

[image: parsed data]
[image: nrfBeacon raw packet data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is quite good. Some remarks:

- Manufacture ID for Apple is 76: `mBuilder.addManufacturerData(76, mManufacturerData.array())`
- iBeacon type is 0x02: `mManufacturerData.put(0, (byte)0x02); // Beacon Identifier`
- length is 0x15: `mManufacturerData.put(1, (byte)0x15); // Beacon Identifier`
- I am not sure if that works: `UUID.fromString("0CF052C297CA407C84F8B62AAC4E9020")`. Usually the `fromString()` method expects something like: `UUID.fromString("F0018B9B-7509-4C31-A905-1A27D39C003D")`

to sum up:

```
protected void setAdvertiseData() {

     AdvertiseData.Builder mBuilder = new AdvertiseData.Builder()

     ByteBuffer mManufacturerData = ByteBuffer.allocate(23);

     byte[] uuid = getIdAsByte(UUID.fromString("0CF052C297CA407C84F8B62AAC4E9020"));

     mManufacturerData.put(0, (byte)0x02);
     mManufacturerData.put(1, (byte)0x15); 

     for (int i=2; i<=17; i++) {
       mManufacturerData.put(i, uuid[i-2]); // adding the UUID
     }

     mManufacturerData.put(18, (byte)0x00); // first byte of Major
     mManufacturerData.put(19, (byte)0x09); // second byte of Major
     mManufacturerData.put(20, (byte)0x00); // first minor
     mManufacturerData.put(21, (byte)0x06); // second minor
     mManufacturerData.put(22, (byte)0xB5); // txPower

     mBuilder.addManufacturerData(76, mManufacturerData.array()); 
     mAdvertiseData = mBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: Correct, I left the Alt-Beacon values in because they were in the tutorial I got the code from. I tried having the Beacon Identifier as 2 bytes (0x00,0x02). When I tried adding the 0x15 (with 00,02) I got a buffer overflow, which I also got with 0xFF and 0x00 (for the length)

Comment: Not adding. Replace the parts I mentioned.

Comment: I mean the byte at index 1. -> `mManufacturerData.put(1, (byte)0xAC); ` -> replace with `mManufacturerData.put(1, (byte)0x15);`

Comment: Just tried these values, this beacon is still showing up as an AltBeacon in nrfConnect (a bluetooth receiving app)

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code and can you present the raw view of the advertisement frame in nrf app? If you change the manufacturer id, it can't be an Altbeacon any longer.

Comment: @user4757074 I just checked your implementation and the screenshot. From my point of view this is a valid iBeacon frame and definitely no AltBeacon format. You can check this with e.g. Beaconscanner: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bridou_n.beaconscanner

Comment: Beaconscanner picked up an iBeacon with my uuid with no changes to the code I posted!!!!