# BLE execute a function near a Bluetooth device

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I have a Bluetooth device, and I try to execute a function when my application is near the device.

I read on an iBeacon technology, but I did not really understand if the iBeacon could be used on all Bluetooth devices as long as you have your UUID, or you need the Bluetooth device have a service that sends a special UUID for iBeacon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the firmware on your Bluetooth device, it is generally simple to set up iBeacon advertising.  You must enable the Bluetooth controller to emit a  manufacturer advertisement  with a specific 22 byte payload.  The details of how you do this is device-dpecific.

That payload contains three identifiers which you may choose, the Proximity UUID is a 16 byte sequence, the major is a two byte sequence and the minor is also a two byte sequence.

You can see the layout of this payload in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19040616).

You can then use the CoreLocation API on iOS and the Android Beacon Library on Android devices to detect the iBeacon advertisement with the same identifiers and make your app react.