# parse the following ibeacon packet

Tags: ibeacon, rssi, tx

I am trying to parse this ibeacon packet received by scanning through a hci socket

```
b'\x01\x03\x00\x18\xbe\x99m\xf3\x14\x1e\x02\x01\x1a\x1a\xffL\x00\x02\x15e\xec\xe2\x90\xc7\xdbM\xd0\xb8\x1aV\xa6-b 2\x00\x00\x00\x02\xc5\xcc'
```

hex format `01 03 00 18 be 99 6d f3 14 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 65 ec e2 90 c7 db 4d d0 b8 1a 56 a6 2d 62 20 32 00 00 00 02 c5 cc`

the parameters after applying the parser are 
'UUID': '65ece290c7db4dd0b81a56a62d622032', 'MAJOR': '0000', 'MINOR': '0002', 'TX': -59, 'RSSI': -60
I am not sure if the RSSI portion of this parsing is right.

Referring to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19040616/10355673 
the last bit of the beacon advertising packet is the TX power value. 
so how do we get the rssi value? here, I have taken rssi to be `cc` and tx to be `c5`. Is this correct?

Comment: I am not sure how the string you show as the beacon packet is formatted.  Typically this is shown as a series of bytes in hex format.  (each byte is 2 characters 0-9 or a-f).  But the string shown often has three characters (e.g. 99m, ffL, 15e, etc). What is this encoding?

Comment: @davidgyoung after applying `struct.unpack` on the byte string it becomes
`01030018be996df3141e02011a1aff4c00021565ece290c7db4dd0b81a56a62d62203200000002c5cc`
I guess this is the hex format you are looking for?

Comment: cleaner format
`01 03 00 18 be 99 6d f3 14 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 65 ec e2 90 c7 db 4d d0 b8 1a 56 a6 2d 62 20 32 00 00 00 02 c5 cc `

Answer (score 1):

There are flags headers before the manufacturer advertisement sequence shown below, but you really don't care about the flags.  Here are the bytes you care about:

```
 ff # manufacturee adv type
 4c 00 # apple Bluetooth company code
 02 15  # iBeacon type code
 65 ec e2 90 c7 db 4d d0 b8 1a 56 a6 2d 62 20 32 # proximity uuid
 00 00 # major 
 00 02 # minor
 c5 # measured power (tx power)
 cc # crc
```

Proximity UUUD: 65ece290-c7db-4dd0-b81a-56a62d622032,
Major: 0,
Minor: 2,
Measured Power: -59 dBm

The RSSI is not part of the transmitted packet, but a measurement taken by the receiver based on the strength of the signal.  It will typically be a slightly different value for each packet that is received.  You get this value from an API on a mobile device or embedded system that fetches it from the bluetooth chip.