# How Identify becone data frame (iBeacone or Eddystone) using raw data?

Tags: ibeacon, zephyr-rtos

How to identify beacon data frame using raw data?

what is adv type in beacon data frame?

Comment: You might find the following cheat sheet helpful:  https://twitter.com/josryke/status/763006284052463617

Answer (score 1):

iBeacon uses a Manufacturer AD Type (0xFF) and Eddystone uses a Service Data AD Type (0x16).

The full iBeacon format is documented in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19040616/1461050)

Google has documented the Eddystone layout [here](https://github.com/google/eddystone/blob/master/protocol-specification.md)