# React native simulated ibeacon detection

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I'm trying to scan the beacons nearby in react native application.

For that I used **react-native-ble-plx** library
https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx

I simulated a beacon using this windows app
https://www.microsoft.com/en-lk/p/beacon-simulator/9nblggh4xvd0?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

I tested my simulated beacon using ble scanner apps and detected my simulated beacon successfully.

But the issue is I cannot get it to detect with the use of **react-native-ble-plx** in my react native application.

It actually shows several devices nearby but it does not show the UUID or name. These data are shown as null.

For example:

```
'device', { serviceUUIDs: null,
      isConnectable: null,
      overflowServiceUUIDs: null,
      txPowerLevel: null,
      serviceData: null,
      manufacturerData: 'TEACFCd6h5jcoxKqh9ACQqwTAAOBqZYcxQ==',
      name: null,
      mtu: 23,
      rssi: -47,
      solicitedServiceUUIDs: null,
      localName: null,
      id: '32:BD:32:6C:E9:C2',
```

But when I used a real device like a bluetooth headset or similar, then it will get detected properly with showing its name , uuid etc.

Why can't I get my simulated beacon to show up in my react native app when scanned.

FYI : i'm using a real device to do the scanning. (Samsung S10 - Android 11)

This is my code

I have a button as follows

```
<Button title="Scan devices" onPress={scanDevices} />
```

and my function

```
const scanDevices = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    // scan devices
    manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, scannedDevice) => {
      if (error) {
        console.warn(error);
      }

      // if a device is detected add the device to the list by dispatching the action into the reducer
      if (scannedDevice) {
        console.log('device', scannedDevice);
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_DEVICE', payload: scannedDevice });
      }
    });

    // stop scanning devices after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      manager.stopDeviceScan();
      setIsLoading(false);
    }, 55000);
  };
```

Note that I'm new to ble technology and wondering whether I missed something here.

Answer (score 0):

For iBeacon advertisements, the beacon fields will be encoded inside the manufacturerData as described in my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69466133/1461050.

Do not expect to see the iBeacon ProximityUUID field show up in the serviceUuIDs field or other UUID fields.  That is not how iBeacon works.