# yj-16009 iBeacon Proximity BLT beacon

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon, esp32, android-sensors, proximity

I'm making a project with Esp32 whroom, so I bought the yj-16009 iBeacon [DataSheet](http://www.holyiot.com/tp/2019042815352698708.pdf) and I'm trying to get it to work as wireless Bluetooth proximity sensor like in this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azT2rosEo0k&t=145s&ab_channel=DavyWybiral)

I used the this [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKRFf.png) from the video and the esp32 is monitoring and showing BLT scanning results like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm6dl.png) the results shown are after I turned off any BLT device around so first I don't understand what it is reading, and second after I turn on the iBeacon the results remain with the same range of numbers no matter if I get the iBeacon closer or farther, therefor I came to the conclusion that it doesn't recognize the iBeacon sensor for some reason.

I also download an app named LightBlue which does recognize the iBeacon sensor.

My question is if anyone knows how to make the esp32 recognize the iBeacon sensor. Another thing I tried to find any information about this sensor and there is no info about it anywhere. I have read on other questions here that it might need to be programmed somehow which I don't know how to do because there is no info online. So if anyone is familiar with this kind of sensor and can help me figure how to make the ibeacon to work like the video above as a Bluetooth Proximity device it would be a blessing.

Comment: You say “the esp32 is monitoring perfectly as shown, but for some reason the esp32 wont see the ibeacon”.  What does it mean that it is “monitoring perfectly”?  Please be specific:  what works and what doesn’t work?  You should really paste your code in the question instead of linking to a video with code.

Comment: first thx for your  response , i edited the question as u said hope its more clear now

Answer (score 1):

The code you reference is just scanning for any BLE advertisements (iBeacon or otherwise) and printing out the RSSI signal strength of each detection.  The reason you do not see the RSSI change when you move the beacon is because the ESP32 is probably picking up non-iBeacon adverts from your phone, laptop and other Bluetooth enabled devices in the vicinity which are not moving (there are more around you than you think!)

In order to make the device detect iBeacon only (and not all the other devices) you need to change the C code to do a few more things:

1. Access the bytes of the advertisement payload and use them as follows:
2. Compare the beginning of these bytes to see if they include the iBeacon byte sequence FF 4C 00 02 15
3. If the above byte sequence is not in the advertising data, ignore that detection — it is not an iBeacon advert
4. If it does include that byte sequence, decode the next 16 bytes as the iBeacon uuid, the next two bytes as the major and the next two bytes as the minor.  See my answer here:  [What is the iBeacon Bluetooth Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906988/what-is-the-ibeacon-bluetooth-profile)
5. Print out the identifiers along with the RSSI that the code already prints.