# Broadcast message on Ibeacon Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, ibeacon

I have set up Ibeacon raspberry pi
it is detecting bluetooths

```
root@raspberrypi:~# hcitool scan
 Scanning ...
    90:C1:15:34:84:77       jassi
    30:14:4A:8B:95:45       TVBluetooth
```

Now I want it to broadcast messages 
How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

You can make an iBeacon out of a Raspberry Pi [using this tutorial](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/09/how-to-make-an-ibeacon-out-of-a-raspberry-pi.html).  My company also sells all the parts you need as [iBeacon Development Kits](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/ibeacon-development-kit.html) that have this pre-assembled with the necessary software.  If you want, we can also send you [just the SD](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/ibeacon-development-kit-sd-card.html) card so you can use the Raspberry Pi you already have.

If you want a utility to do more advanced iBeacon detection on the Raspberry Pi, [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790504/1461050).  We are still working out some of the kinks, but we will eventually release it with the iBeacon Development Kit as well.

Comment: Thanks, But I have already made the beacon. In fact, I followed the tutorial you have just sent. But I want advertise information on it, how would I do that. broadcast a message in other words.

Comment: iBeacons only transmit a 3-part identifier.  They do not advertise additional data.  Making a phone display a human readable message based on seeing an iBeacon requires tying these identifiers to the readable text in a lookup table.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20649213/1461050

Comment: How can I build these tables and data, as I am new to this I am not aware of how I would display this data

Comment: The answer depends on the platform you are using to detect the iBeacons.  Are you using iOS, Android, or a Raspberry Pi?  The solution is somewhat different for each.

Comment: Well I have ibeacon made using raspberry pi, I just want it to display messages on an device that comes in range

Comment: Here is the key point: iBeacons cannot make a message display on a device unless you write an app and install it on that device. The app only sees the 3-part iBeacon identifier, and it is responsible for translating that into messages to display to the user.  How to make such an app is different for iOS, Android or other platforms.

Comment: Oh Okay, So what about ibeacon showing or pairing soon as the device enters the range? Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, iBeacons do not pair at all -- they are connectionless transmit-only devices.  As for "showing... as the device enters the range" the operating system (iOS or Android) will be able to see the iBeacon when it cones into range. But this detection is invisible to the user (nothing shows up on the screen) unless you have an app installed to make something visible happen. Bottom line: you must have an app installed to make a mobile device interact with iBeacons.

Comment: You may be mistaking iBeacons with BLE devices in general. iBeacons make use of BLE technology, but iBeacons simply broadcast a limited set of information (UUID, major, minor). There is no "active" communication with an iBeacon. On the other hand, BLE devices allow more interactions. In theory, you could transmit a message via a BLE peripheral device (via Services and Characteristics), but the apps need to know what to do with it.