# How to emulate BLE transmitter with Bluez?

Tags: debian, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I have Debian 8.1 with Bluez 5.23. I know how to connect with BLE transmitter with `hcitool` and `gatttool`. But is there any way to emulate BLE transmitter on Debian?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific...  Are you trying to just send out ad packets?  Do you want to have a GATT server?  Whatever it is, the answer is probably "yes", but some things may be harder than other things.

Comment: @TimTisdall, yes, I want to start with ad packets.

Comment: You can do it with `sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 12 34 56 78`.  That turns undirected advertising on with IAR data of `12 34 56 78`.  You'll have to read up on the IAR format to put something useful in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use BlueZ Stack As A Peripheral (Advertiser)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151360/use-bluez-stack-as-a-peripheral-advertiser)

Comment: ^_^  you don't need to vote to close your own question...